# How to get my company's proxy transparent?

Tags: windows, proxy, credentials, transparent

In my company there is a proxy that requires credentials.

I use Windows XP and I want to apply an indirection layer in my tcp/ip stack that makes this completely transparent.

For example it would be nice a **software that I can configure with my company proxy and act as I don't have any proxy in my network**.

With this software I don't have to configure software that don't consider my default proxy settings done with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Does this belong on superuser.com?

Comment: superuser.com is by invite only

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably over, but in case the subject is still of interest, there are some possiblities with Fiddler, which are outline in the answers to this :
[Configuring Fiddler to use company network's proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989466/configuring-fiddler-to-use-company-networks-proxy) : essentially fiddler is configured to cache the credentials needed to access the internet, and your access from local box goes via fiddler proxy first.