# dnu restore behind proxy with authentication

Tags: authentication, proxy, visual-studio-2015, dnx, dnu

I'm trying to create an .NET CORE application on VS2015.

But I'm unable to get "dnu restore" with success behind a proxy with authentication.

I allways get a: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required)

In other features from VS like "Extensions and Updates" I'm prompted for user and password, but they aren't reused by "dnu restore".

I notice that "dnu restore" runs as a "dnx.exe" call inside VS...

Where is he looking for the proxy configuration? namely the proxy authentication (user+password)?

I tryed three diferent aproaches for configuring the proxy: 
 - configuring it on devenv.exe.config 
 - using Proxifier 
 - using Fiddler.

Unable to have success with any of the three.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance,
 Miguel

Comment: I solve it using Fiddler and configuring it, like in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989466/configuring-fiddler-to-use-company-networks-proxy