# Package manager in Visual Studio 2015 "407 (Proxy Authentication Required)"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, package-managers, nugetgallery

*I understand this is an often asked question, however after days of research I've not found an answer to this particular problem.*

---

I have a new ASP.NET 5 (Core 1.0) MVC template that I'm trying to add a package to however each and every time I get in the Package Manager output:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required).
```

and the following at the top of solution explorer:

[image]

my settings look fine and I am able to browse packages in the 'Manage Packages for Solution' screen.

I understand I'm being requested to supply credentials so where do I enter them?  On the other hand all other applications on my machine have validated internet access, so why should I?

Any ideas / pointers are very welcome.

**Visual Studio 2015** - 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 
**NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015** - 3.3.0.167

---

Top section of Package Manager output:

Installing NuGet package AutoMapper.4.2.1.
Successfully installed 'AutoMapper 4.2.1' to CustomerPortal
========== Finished ==========
PATH=.\node_modules.bin;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\medmondson.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\medmondson.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\lib\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.dll" restore "M:\visual studio 2015\Projects\CustomerPortal\src\CustomerPortal" -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU"
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
  GET http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/
  GET https://www.postsharp.net/nuget/packages/
Restoring packages for M:\visual studio 2015\Projects\CustomerPortal\src\CustomerPortal\project.json
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='AutoMapper'
  GET http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='AutoMapper'
  GET https://www.postsharp.net/nuget/packages/FindPackagesById()?id='AutoMapper'
Warning: FindPackagesById: AutoMapper
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='AutoMapper'
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Collections.Immutable'
  GET http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Collections.Immutable'
  GET https://www.postsharp.net/nuget/packages/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Collections.Immutable'
Warning: FindPackagesById: AutoMapper
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  GET https://www.postsharp.net/nuget/packages/FindPackagesById()?id='AutoMapper'
Warning: FindPackagesById: AutoMapper
  Response status code does not indicate success: 407 (Proxy Authentication Required).

## Update

I've managed to capture a non-working request (returning 407) and a working request with the **only difference being the content of the Proxy-Authorization header** which is longer.  This would suggest the proxy authentication does exist but it's using a different protocol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to modify the **32 bit** machine.config (assumption being VS runs in 32 bit) to add the `<system.net>` section but omitting anything within the `<defaultProxy>` tag:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="True" enabled="True" />
</system.net>
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the defaultProxy element is empty, the proxy settings from Internet Explorer will be used.

This is perfect for me as every other application on my machine works - including IE.

manchine.config location (Win 7): %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

---

### Note

*I resolved this thanks to @user3063127 pointing me in the right direction (you have an upvote). As far as I can tell this only affects package restore on DNX projects and may well be fixed when RC2 is released.*

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago. For me it has helped to put in the the following in the machine.config (Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Config)

```
<system.net>
   <settings>
       <ipv6 enabled="True"/>
   </settings>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="True" enabled="True">
       <proxy proxyaddress="http://your.proxyserver.ip:port"/>
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem with visual studio code as well

Answer (score 4):

1. Updated to latest nuget.exe 1st

   ```
   nuget update self
   ```
2. Added proxy details to the config file:

   ```
   nuget config -Set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.company.com:port
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify file 2 .config files:

**for Visual Studio 2015**

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\vsn.exe.config`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

**for Visual Studio 2017**

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\vsn.exe.config`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

```xml
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://yourproxy:proxyport" />
    <bypasslist>
      <add address="(.*\.)?anyotherdomain\.com?(.*)" />
      <add address="(.*\.)?nuget\.org?(.*)" />
      <add address="192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" />
    </bypasslist>
  </defaultProxy>
  <settings>
    <ipv6 enabled="false"/>
    <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
  </settings>
</system.net>
```

The bypass for `nuget.org` will work if, without the proxy, you still can get it's IP from DNS server and nothing else is blocking it.

Also need this to install `nuget`

Open the file `C:\Users\[YOUR_USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` and add inside the `<configuration> <\configuration>` tag the following:

```xml
<config>
  <add key="http_proxy" value="http://yourproxy:proxyport" />
</config>
```

Taken from [Marco Mengoli's Blog](http://marcomengoli.github.io/miscellaneous/NuGet-proxy-config/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Fiddler installed, tick the option 'Automatically Authenticate' under the Rules option, should fix the above issue.

[Selecting the Automatically Authenticate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taAJN.png)

Got this from the following post
[Configuring Fiddler to use company network's proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989466/configuring-fiddler-to-use-company-networks-proxy)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the proxy server details, you can go with other workaround to overcome this error "407 (Proxy Authorisation Required.)"

**Workaround**:
1. Download/Install Fiddler
2. Click Menu Rules -> Automatically Authenticate

Without closing Fiddler, now try to do restore package in Visual Studio. It should now restore the packages without any proxy error.

This is not a neat solution, but still an alternate workaround to resolve this issue. This solution tries to utilise Fiddler as Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have wrong proxy credentials in Credential Manager. Try to remove it.

Control Panel -> User Account -> Credential Manager.

Remove proxy credentials resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding proxy username, password fixed my 407 authentication issue.

Place the following snippet in NuGet.config file located at C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming

```
<configuration>

   <config>
     <add key="http_proxy" value="http://my.proxy.address:port" />
     <add key="http_proxy.user" value="mydomain\myUserName" />
     <add key="http_proxy.password" value="[base64 encoded Password]" />
   </config>

</configuration>
```

Ref: https://forums.asp.net/t/2096179.aspx?Proxy+407+Access+Denied