# Proxy inside Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I'm trying to find api requests for a mobile app.

I am using Fiddler to monitor network traffic, and Android Studio.
I have installed certificates and can listen to traffic, but I have a task to access an app that can only be accessed from a certain country, I have tried using a VPN but I have not been able to access the resource. So here is the question, can I use not a VPN, but a purchased proxy server, somehow inside feddler, i.e. use a proxy inside a proxy. Maybe there are some other ways?

I am using Fiddler to monitor network traffic, and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually configure an upstream proxy within Fiddler Classic:

Menu Tools -> Options -> Gateway

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, but when I try to enable the proxy this way, it only asks for authorization in the browser, application traffic does not go through this proxy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Miki323 Not sure if Fiddler supports external proxies that require authentication. But using FiddlerScript you can manually add proxy authentication as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4945865/150978